# Cannot display data on textview which taken from socket

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I am having trouble about my chat application using sockets. 
My Server program is written on C# and it is able to support multiple clients. Server receives messages and sends them back to all clients. I tried if it works with different clients written in C#(about recieving data from server)
In my Android client, I connect to server successfully and send messages to server correctly. When I try to take them from server using the socket, nothing happens. 
This is myMenu class where I connect to server.

```
public class myMenu extends Activity{
    TextView textResponse;
    EditText editTextAddress;
    EditText editPort;//new guy :P
    EditText editNick;//another new guy
    public static String nick;
    public static Socket socket = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectButton);
        textResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);
        editTextAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipaddress);
        editPort = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
        editNick = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nick);
        //When clicked on connect button in main screen
        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(editTextAddress.getText().toString(),
                                                            Integer.parseInt(editPort.getText().toString()));
                myClientTask.execute();
                nick = editNick.getText().toString();
                if(socket!=null)
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.chatapp.CONNECTBUTTON"));
                else
                    textResponse.setText("Connection failed");
            }
        });
    }
    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";

        MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.d("doInBackGround","socket Created");
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            String line=null;
            int bytesRead;
            BufferedReader reader;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                Log.d("doInBackGround","connected to server ");
                InputStream dataComing = (InputStream)(myMenu.socket).getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataComing, "UTF-8"));
                line=reader.readLine();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return line;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String line) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(line);
            if (line != null) {
                TextView sentMessages;
                sentMessages=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sentMessages);
                sentMessages.append((CharSequence) line);
             }  
        }


    }

}
```

In ConnectButton class I send the messages to server when clicked on send button.

```
public class ConnectButton extends Activity{
    public static EditText messageWritten;
    public static TextView sentMessages;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send_message);
        messageWritten = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);


        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*MessageDisplayer displayer= new MessageDisplayer();
                displayer.execute();*/

                //new MessageDisplayer().execute((String) null);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //use it in a method otherwise not working!messageWritten.getText().toString();
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(myMenu.socket.getOutputStream()));
                    final String message = messageWritten.getText().toString(); //get the text message on the text field
                    Log.d("onClick", "message written to string");
                    messageWritten.setText(""); 
                    out.write(myMenu.nick + ": " +message);
                    out.flush();
                    //out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(myMenu.socket.getOutputStream()));
            out.write("exit");//when exit is written server disconnects from client
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            myMenu.socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

After all these I want program to revieve messages back from server and display them on sentMessages textView. What am I doing wrong I really don't understand. Also my xml files are below. Thanks in advance. 
send_message.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.chatapp.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/enter_message"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sentMessages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="@string/list_messages"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.chatapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:text="@string/enter_IP"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ipaddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_user"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/port"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ipaddress"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ipaddress"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connectButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/response"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/connect" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/response"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/connectButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:text="@string/response" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/connectButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/port"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/port"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nick"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="@string/nick"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/port"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ipaddress"
        android:text="@string/port"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you checking for `-1` as the return from `.Read()` ? The documentation [specifies `0` for EOF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) - but if you want to be sure, checking for positive vs non-positive (i.e. either `> 0` or `<= 0`) is reasonable

Comment: It was meant to be a positive number check you're correct but it has nothing to do with my problem I think. It just sets the response string which returns if connection is failed or not to user of application. I'm removing this piece of code then but like I said nothing changes.